# color lines with same color if condition in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following recyclerview that can return multiple rows with the same date in different or equal date, but with different treatments. I want that when you return more than one line with the same date, color them all the same color.
in below my script:

```
for(int i=1;i <=artControle.size()-1;i++){
            //item.repas.getLibelleRepas().equalsIgnoreCase(filterPattern)
            String dateControle1=df.format("dd/MM/yyyy",artControle.get(i).getDateControle()).toString();
            String dateControle2=df.format("dd/MM/yyyy",artControle.get(i++).getDateControle()).toString();
            Log.d("Date Controle1 " , dateControle1);


            if (dateControle2.equals(dateControle1)) {
                Log.d("Date Controle 2Increm" , dateControle2);
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8EAF6"));
                //  holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }else {
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                //  holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"));
                //viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BBDEFB"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: where are you executing this code?

Comment: Android Studio thanks in advance

Comment: In what function or class?

Comment: public class RecyclerviewAdapter and function public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) thanks in advance